# push notification not coming for app to app calling using sinch

Tags: ios, voip, sinch

I am developing application for audio calling using sinch framework. 
I don't know what i miss while setup. when app is in foreground everything works fine. i can do audio call and can talk.

But when app is in background. I am expecting a voip push notification but its not coming.

I had uploaed voip certificate over sinch website.
I can receive push notification using knuff

**Code**

```
-(void)initSinchClientWithUserId:(NSString *)userId{
sinchClient = [Sinch clientWithApplicationKey:@"3a130480-*****e370f0"
                            applicationSecret:@"XP0E******3Oh2PxCWw=="
                              environmentHost:@"sandbox.sinch.com"
                                       userId:userId];
[sinchClient setSupportCalling:YES];
[sinchClient enableManagedPushNotifications];
sinchClient.delegate =self;
sinchClient.callClient.delegate =self;
[sinchClient start];
[sinchClient startListeningOnActiveConnection];
if (pushTokenData) {
    [sinchClient registerPushNotificationData:pushTokenData];
}
```

}

Push notification set up

```
    self.push = [Sinch managedPushWithAPSEnvironment:SINAPSEnvironmentAutomatic];
self.push.delegate = self;
[self.push setDesiredPushTypeAutomatically];
[self.push registerUserNotificationSettings];
```

**Saving token**

```
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didUpdatePushCredentials:(PKPushCredentials *)pushCredentials forType:(PKPushType)type{

    if (sinchClient) {
        [sinchClient registerPushNotificationData:pushCredentials.token];
    }

}
```

**Handle Notification but its never called**

```
 - (void)managedPush:(id<SINManagedPush>)unused
didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload
            forType:(NSString *)pushType {

     [self handleRemoteNotification:payload];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if (pushTokenData) {
    [sinchClient registerPushNotificationData:pushTokenData];
}

[sinchClient registerPushNotificationData:pushTokenData]; should really be called when you get the push token, not in init or app launching.

Comment: I had called in the same way..  when sinchClient is intialized and if i got the pushTokenData. i had registerPushNotificationData:pushTokenData. in the same way if . didUpdatePushCredentials called and sinth is already intialized i had registerPushNotificationData:pushTokenData

Comment: Are you using a VoIP certificate or old APNS cert?

Comment: I am using voip certificate and one question will apple approve>